# list and classify the singularities of the following functions giving the order of the poles:

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm looking to list and classify the singularities of the following functions giving the order of the
poles:

$(i)$ $\frac{1}{z^2} + \frac{1}{z^2+1}$

and

$(ii)$ $\frac{z}{\sin(z)}$

**My attempt Part(i)**

Ok so I don't really know how to approach this question.

for for first one I have that at $z=0$ we have a simple pole (pole of order $0$)

and $f$ is differentiable everywhere else except when $z^2=-1$

so we have another singularity at $i$

**Part(ii)**

$f$ is differentiable everywhere except when $\sin(z)=0$

roots of $\sin(z) = \pi n$ for $n \in \mathbb Z$

ord$(\sin(z), \pi n) = 1$

ord$(\frac{1}{sin(z)}, \pi n) = -1$

so $f$ has a simple pole at $\pi n$

and ord$(f,0)$ = $1$ so $f$ has a removable singularity at $z=0$

Can somone help me tidy up these questions. Should I utilise the Laurent Series more??

Answer (score 0):

Part (i) : We have a pole of order $2$ at $0$ and a  pole of order $1$  at $z =\pm i$.

Part (ii): As you have said there is  a simple pole (i.e. pole of order $1$) at each of the points $n\pi$ ($n$ an integer) and a removable singularity at $0$.